# pass interface implementation to a method and invoke AddTransient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, datacontext

How do I pass a class/type to a method which configures IServiceCollection and add's a transient service? I have a generic approach, but how do I pass the implementation of an interface?

TDBContextAccessor will always be an interface. So I want to pass the interface and the implementation of it.

Code:

```
public class CustomDB<TDBContext, TDBContextAccessor> : CustomDB<TDBContext>, ICustomDB<TDBContext, TDBContextAccessor> where TDBContext : DbContext where TDBContextAccessor : class
{
    private readonly TDBContextAccessor _accessor;

    public CustomDB(string connectionString, TDBContextAccessor accessor) : base(connectionString)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public IServiceCollection ConfigureDBContext(IServiceCollection services, TDBContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        return services
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<TDBContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(this.ConnectionString))
            .AddTransient<TDBContextAccessor>();
    }
}
```

I've tried

```
.AddTransient<TDBContextAccessor, typeof(accessor)>()
```

but that doesn't work. How can I pass the implementation of defined TDBContextAccessor?

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I found you pass the `typeof(accessor)` as the impelmenttype of the TDBContextAccessor. But the `typeof(accessor)` value is still the TDBContextAccessor that means the code should be this `.AddTransient<TDBContextAccessor, TDBContextAccessor >()`.

The right way should be `.AddTransient<TDBContextAccessor, TheClasswhichhasalreadyimpletenttheTDBContextAccessor>()`.

More details about how to use AddTransient, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddTransient__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_).

Comment: `typeof(accessor)` wouldn't even compile